# How to delete local files uploaded by CarrierWave to S3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-s3, rubygems, carrierwave

In Rails 5 using the CarrierWave gem to upload attachments to Amazon S3, how can I get CarrierWave to delete the local copy of the image after successfully uploading it to S3?

Answer (score 2):

If your /tmp dir gets full of rack tmp upload garbage, you can delete these in a callback like so: look at [here](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/wiki/How-to:-Delete-cache-garbage-directories)

```
class FileUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  after :store, :delete_old_tmp_file

  # remember the tmp file
  def cache!(new_file)
    super
    @old_tmp_file = new_file
  end

  def delete_old_tmp_file(dummy)
    @old_tmp_file.try :delete
  end
end
```

Comment: @Avishai if you satisfied with my answer vote up and make it correct